# Unicode scalar value in Swift

Tags: swift, unicode

In Swift Programming Language 3.0, chapter on string and character, the book states

> A Unicode scalar is any Unicode code point in the range U+0000 to
>   U+D7FF inclusive or U+E000 to U+10FFFF inclusive. Unicode scalars do
>   not include the Unicode surrogate pair code points, which are the code
>   points in the range U+D800 to U+DFFF inclusive

What does this mean?

Comment: An Unicode scalar value is just any Unicode codepoint (= any _entry_ in the Unicode character list) that is not a surrogate (=a codepoint that has no meaning alone but has to be used in a pair to form a character, see for example Hangul **** character). Note that an Unicode scalar value may not be a _meaningful_ character alone, think about the composition of character **à** which is made by two codepoints: **a** and U+0300 COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT. You may want to also read [How can I perform a Unicode aware character by character comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27229589/1207195)

Comment: [What is a surrogate pair?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31986614/995714), [What is a “surrogate pair” in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5903008/995714)

Answer (score 3):

A **Unicode Scalar** is a code point which is not serialised as a pair of UTF-16 code units.

A *code point* is the number resulting from encoding a character in the Unicode standard. For instance, the code point of the letter A is 0x41 (or 65 in decimal).

A *code unit* is each group of bits used in the serialisation of a code point. For instance, UTF-16 uses one or two code units of 16 bit each.

The letter A is a Unicode Scalar because it can be expressed with only one code unit: 0x0041. However, less common characters require two UTF-16 code units. This pair of code units is called *surrogate pair*. Thus, Unicode Scalar may also be defined as: any code point except those represented by surrogate pairs.

---

The answer from courteouselk is correct by the way, this is just a more plain english version.

Answer (score 1):

From [Unicode FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2):

> **Q:** What are surrogates?
>
> **A:** Surrogates are code points from two special ranges of Unicode values, reserved for use as the leading, and trailing values of paired code units in UTF-16. Leading, also called high, surrogates are from D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub>, and trailing, or low, surrogates are from DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub>. They are called surrogates, since they do not represent characters directly, but only as a pair.

Basically, surrogates are codepoints that are reserved for special purposes and promised to never encode a character on their own but always as a first codepoint in a pair of UTF-16 encoding.

**[UPD]**  Also, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF):

> The Unicode standard permanently reserves these code point values for UTF-16 encoding of the high and low surrogates, and they will never be assigned a character, so there should be no reason to encode them. The official Unicode standard says that no UTF forms, including UTF-16, can encode these code points.
>
> However UCS-2, UTF-8, and UTF-32 can encode these code points in trivial and obvious ways, and large amounts of software does so even though the standard states that such arrangements should be treated as encoding errors. It is possible to unambiguously encode them in UTF-16 by using a code unit equal to the code point, as long as no sequence of two code units can be interpreted as a legal surrogate pair (that is, as long as a high surrogate is never followed by a low surrogate). The majority of UTF-16 encoder and decoder implementations translate between encodings as though this were the case<sup>[citation needed]</sup> and Windows allows such sequences in filenames.

Comment: Note "16" in the referenced Unicode FAQ is a *subscript* indicating base-16 (hex) numbers. That is not apparent here, "D80016" is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR.  It took me some time to figure out how to do sub- and superscripts in MD.  Had to embed HTML in the end.