# Why '❌'[0] === '❌' but '✔️'[0] !== '✔️'?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

```
'❌'[0] === '❌' // true
'✔️'[0] === '✔️' // false
'✔️'[0] === '✔'  // true
```

I suspect it's unicode related but would like to understand precisely what is happening and how can I correctly compare such charaters. Why is '✔️' treated differently than '❌'?

I encountered it in this simple char counting

```
'✔️❌✔️❌'.split('').filter(e => e === '❌').length // 2
'✔️❌✔️❌'.split('').filter(e => e === '✔️').length // 0
```

Comment: I think the check-mark is a two-character sequence, while the "X" is not.

Comment: You encountered a surrogate pair: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986614/what-is-a-surrogate-pair

Comment: thorough explication here: [Emojis in Javascript](https://medium.com/reactnative/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb) from this question: [How to convert one emoji character to Unicode codepoint number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419167/how-to-convert-one-emoji-character-to-unicode-codepoint-number-in-javascript)

Comment: It’s not surrogate pairs; this is a _grapheme cluster_ made out of the `U+2714 HEAVY CHECK MARK` and the `U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `✔️` takes two characters:
`"✔️".length === 2`

`"✔️"[0] === "✔"` an `"✔️"[1]` denotes color, I think.

And `"❌".length === 1` so it take only one character.

It's similar to the way emojis with different skin colors work as well.

As to how to compare, I think that `"✔️".codePointAt(0)` (not to confuse with `charCodeAt()`) might help. See https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/:

> codePointAt and fromCodePoint are new methods introduced in ES2015 that can handle unicode characters whose UTF-16 encoding is greater than 16 bits, which includes emojis. Use these instead of charCodeAt, which doesn’t handle emoji correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just checked that '‍‍'.length === 8. Ugh. That's enough programming for today :D

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik ‍‍ is 8 UTF-16 codeunits in length: `0xD83D 0xDC68 0x200D 0xD83D 0xDC69 0x200D 0xD83D 0xDC66`, which when translated to Unicode is 5 codepoints: `U+1F468 MAN` + `U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER` + `U+1F469 WOMAN` + `U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER` + `U+1F466 BOY`, aka `FAMILY: MAN, WOMAN, BOY`

Answer (score 4):

The second char `'✔️'[1]`(code point = 65039) is a `Variation Selector`

> A Variation Selector specifies that the preceding character should be displayed with emoji
> presentation. Only required if the preceding character defaults to
> text presentation.
>
> Often used in Emoji ZWJ Sequences, where one or more characters in the
> sequence have text and emoji presentation, but otherwise default to
> text (black and white) display.
>
> Examples Snowman as text: ☃. Snowman as Emoji: ☃️
>
> Black Heart as text: ❤. Black Heart as Emoji: ❤️ (not so black)
>
> Variation Selector-16 was approved as part of Unicode 3.2 in 2002.

https://unicode-table.com/en/FE0F/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the '✔️' is made up of 2 components. When you output '✔️'[0] you get  '✔', and the black checkmark does not equal the green checkmark.

However, the '❌' is made up of just a single component, so when you output '❌'[0], you get the same thing: '❌'.