# How to split array it includes negative integers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the numbers including '-' values. but getting different values.

```
const arr = '2345-10'.split('');;
console.log(arr);
result : ['2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '1', '0']
```

But expecting a result like this:

`['2', '3', '4', '5', '-1', '0']`

Comment: why dont u map and make it string

Comment: @cmgchess, that's different use. updated the quesiton

Comment: its because the initial question was a duplicate where u had array. u can vote to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.split('');` will turn each character in the string into an item in the resulting array (for characters that aren't [surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986614/what-is-a-surrogate-pair), at least). If you want a `-`, when it appears, to stick to the number that follows, you'll need a different approach, such as a regular expression that matches a digit with an optional leading `-`.

```js
const arr = '2345-10'.match(/-?\d/g);;
console.log(arr);
```

But note that due to the format of the input string, this will only work if you always want single digits. `23` will always be interpreted as `'2', '3'` and not `'23'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex, just split it and detect if the previous element of `n` is `'-'`, then return `-n` and filter it so that the final result contains no `'-'`.

```js
const arr = '2345-10'.split('').map((n, index, array) => array.at(index - 1) === '-' ? '-' + n : n).filter(n => n !== '-');
console.log(arr);
```